# How to open a path with forward slashes on Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, git, git-bash, explorer

Run `git --exec-path` gets `C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core`, I can open this path in the File Explorer without issues.

But when using `explorer "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core"`, the folder can't be opened successfully, I assume it's because the path contains forward slashes.

So, how to open a path with forward slashes on Windows?

Comment: Try `explorer C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core`

Comment: @ElpieKay `explorer "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core"` could do the job, but the question is asking for opening a path with forward slashes through the command line.

Comment: *Most* Windows command line utilities *can* open files using forward slashes, as the underlying system calls allow that. However, most of them try to *treat* things in a forward slash as an option. You have to somehow get past the "treat it as an option" step. How to do that depends on the command. It's not a Git issue, it's purely an issue with whichever commands you're running.

Comment: @torek Thanks for the pointer, can I do that with `explorer.exe`?

Comment: I have no idea: I try to avoid using Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using Git Bash, try:

```sh
explorer $(cygpath -w $(git --exec-path))
```